# Searching python list using for loop and conditional statements

Tags: python, python-2.7, for-loop, conditional-statements

```
a = [1,1,1,4,4,4,5]
b = [20150602, 20150603, 20150604, 20150605, 20150606, 20150607,20150608]
c = zip(a,b)

output = []
for i in range(0, len(c)-1):
    if c[i][0] == c[i+1][0] and c[i+1][1] - c[i][1] <= 3:
        output.append(c[i])
print output
```

This code searches 2 lists using conditionals. If element n == element n+1 in list a AND (element n+1) - (element n)<= 3 in list b .....it prints the results. The problem I'm having is that it cuts off 1 element that should be printing. (i.e. This code will output

```
[(1, 20150602), (1, 20150603), (4, 20150605), (4, 20150606)]
```

but should be outputting

```
[(1, 20150602), (1, 20150603), (1,20150604), (4, 20150605), (4, 20150606), (4, 20150607)])
```

Comment: For the third element in each "set", your condition no longer holds since the next element doesn't have a matching `a`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See the second append to the output list.  :)

```
In [14]:

a = [1,1,1,4,4,4,5]
b = [20150602, 20150603, 20150604, 20150605, 20150606, 20150607,20150608]
c = zip(a,b)

output = []
for i in range(0, len(c)-1):
    if c[i][0] == c[i+1][0] and c[i+1][1] - c[i][1] <= 3:
        output.append(c[i])
        output.append(c[i+1])
    output = sorted(list(set(output)))
print output



[(1, 20150602), (1, 20150603), (1, 20150604), (4, 20150605), (4, 20150606), (4, 20150607)]
```

Comment: This will cause duplicates.

Comment: yep, prints duplicates......getting the extra values but printing duplicates as well.

Comment: I updated answer.  Assumes that all items in the list are unique.

Comment: very slick @Andrew_Farber

Comment: since when does 1 == 4?

Comment: ? @Harpal This output satisfies the textual requirements

Comment: @Harpal we compare elements in the input lists.  the output does not require that we compare 1 and 4.

Comment: then why in the if statement is there: c[i][0] == c[i+1][0]

Comment: c[i][0] == c[i+1][0] refers to the input which we zip together (i.e. c = zip(a,b)).  we update the output if the input satisfies the conditions.

Answer (score 0):

```
a = [1,1,1,4,4,4,5]
b = [20150602, 20150603, 20150604, 20150605, 20150606, 20150607,20150608]
c = zip(a,b)

output = []
for i in range(0, len(c)-1):
    if c[i][0] == c[i+1][0] and c[i+1][1] - c[i][1] <= 3:
        output.append(c[i])
    elif c[i][0] != c[i+1][0]:
        print 'equality failed for numbers: %d and %d' % (c[i][0], c[i+1][0])
    elif c[i+1][1] - c[i][1] > 3:
        print 'Subtraction is greater than three for: %d and %d' % (c[i][1], c[i+1][1])

print output
```

output:

```
equality failed for numbers: 1 and 4
equality failed for numbers: 4 and 5
[(1, 20150602), (1, 20150603), (4, 20150605), (4, 20150606)]
```

The reason you are missing two elements is because when `i` in the for loop is 2  `c[i][0]` will return 1. Now, when this section of the if statement is performed: `c[i][0] == c[i+1][0]` it returns false because `c[i][0]` returns 1 and `c[i+1][0]` returns 4 and they do not equal each other. The same happens when `i` is equal to 5.

Comment: I'll look this over more later.....but this solution prints too much information.....there is not a need for a print statement regarding failed iterations.......also, there is not a need to compare integers in list a.......the only requirement is to find cases where List 1(n) == List1(other n) AND List 2 (other n) - List 2 (n) <= 3

Comment: This is by no means a solution, but tries to explain why you are not getting your desired output